# How do I unmount flashdrive in chromium?

Tags: linux, chromium

How do I unmount one in chromium? when I type in command unmount I get an error:

```
bash: unmount: command not found
```

???

Comment: Try umount instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way of writing it is:

```
umount
```

not 'unmount' (forget the n: not `u-n-mount`, `u-mount`)